# How do I create multiple text labels with selective italics in a graph using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have constructed a grouped line graph using `ggplot2`.

I have used the annotate function in ggplot2 to enter the p-values for t-tests of each day's data as labels.

I need to turn each 'p' into an italic while preserving the normal text for the
equals sign and the number. The code for the labels as they appear in the graph is as follows

```
annotate("text", x = 1:7, y = c(15,30,35.7,29.6,38.2,37.1,43),
label = c("p = .36","p = .05","p = .20","p = .13","p = .47","p = .12","p = .97"),
           size = 4.2)
```

I have tried creating an object using `bquote`, which handles italics quite well. But that seems to require using the `text` function which is not recognized in the `ggplot2` package.

The problem is that I can't find a way to create a composite vector of labels
with partial italics and partial normal text.

Answer (score 6):

```
qplot(0,0,geom="blank") + annotate("text", x=0, y=0 , label="italic(p)==0.2", parse=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you baptiste! Of course Murphy's law dictates that the day after I finally lose patience trying to find the answer online and ask stackoverflow I find the answer myself the following morning, just before the answer that would have answered my question. And yes it was the parse argument and discovering the plotmath commands that got me there. Thankyou so much for your help.